# Wrapping python object in C/C++

Tags: python, ctype

I know that you can create ctype objects in Python, but I was wondering if there is a way to wrap Python objects in C/C++ inside a Python environment. More specifically, what I wish to do is wrap an object in C/C++ so I can deference a pointer that points to this object. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,
first you have to install python-dev, if you are using ubuntu:

```
apt-get install python-dev -y
```

then take a look at this documentation :
https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#building-arbitrary-values

it will enable you to use python objects at c\c++

also you can map between many of python datatypes and C/C++
if you have python script and you want to pass values from it to C/C++ code you can pass the values and then you can map it from the python datatypes to C/C++ datatypes.